# IE responseXML getelementsbytagname

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

```
if (xmlRequest.status == 200) 
if (xmlRequest.responseXML)
var xmlElement = xmlRequest.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("item"); 
rest of codes
```

**The parsing working all except internet explorer.**

what should the var xmlElement be when its returning is null for internet explorer?

var xmlElement = xmlRequest.responseXML ... ?

Comment: Because IE does not implement `responseXML` ?

Comment: @Raynos This is not true. I'd say it doesn't support `getElementsByTagName` in objects returned by `responseXML`.

Comment: @duri maybe he needs `responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName` ?

Comment: what can I use then instead of the getElementsByTagName

Comment: @CCCam Try `xmlRequest.responseXML.selectNodes('your XPath expression')` but I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

When responseXML is returning null, that normally means there is an error with the XML.

Are you sure that the document returned is valid XML?

Open up the response directly in the browser, if there is an error, the browser will point you to it.